# Kentico: Amazon S3 Periodically Malfunctioning

Tags: amazon-s3, kentico

The Kentico site I am currently working on has the requirement of storing all document & images to the Amazon S3 cloud. I've gone through Kentico's [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/working-with-physical-files-using-the-api/configuring-file-system-providers/configuring-amazon-s3) on how to configure Amazon S3 and am fairly confident that has been done correctly. I have been able to upload all of the images to S3 via Kentico's Media Library module.

The problem I am having is, periodically and seemingly without cause the Media Library module reverts back to storing newly uploaded content to the local file system rather than to S3 & then maybe an hour will pass at which time if I open the Media Library again it shows the S3 images as it should.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could cause this to happen seemingly randomly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed when looking at my S3 bucket using **S3 Browser** all files and folders were converted to lowercase. I was able to resolve my problem by changing all of the **Media Library** folders to lowercase. I also recommend making sure there are no special characters. After this I went into my mapping file and changed the file path references to lowercase as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a code in place which maps only certain folders to your Amazon S3? It's the following section of documentation - [Storing files in different buckets](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/working-with-physical-files-using-the-api/configuring-file-system-providers/configuring-amazon-s3#ConfiguringAmazonS3-Storingfilesindifferentbuckets).
If so, make sure the definition of the class is the same as in documentation so that it is registered correctly in the system.

Also, make sure that nobody is renaming the media library structure (e.g. folder names) or tampering with a default Media libraries folder setting (**Settings application -> Content -> Media -> Media libraries folder**). This could also affect the way system maps media files to S3.